# How can I correctly center and size images so that they look good on both desktop and mobile without clipping?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with some images on it:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #pictureframe {
            width: 100%
            background-color: #00000066;
        }

        #pictureframe > img {
            max-height: 90%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            border: solid 2em #000000;
            border-radius: 1em;
            cursor: pointer;
            overflow-x: scroll;
        }

        .isHidden {
            display: none;
            visibility: hidden;
            z-index: -1;
        }

        .isHidden > img {
            z-index: -1;
        }

        .isVisible {
            display: block;
            visibility: visible;
            z-index: 99;
        }

        .isVisible > img {
            z-index: 100;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pictureframe"><img src="" /></div>
    <div id="pictures">
        <!-- pictures here ... -->
        <div class="cell"><img src="./images/image01.jpg" width="100px" loading="lazy" /></div>
        <!-- pictures here ... -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const pictureframe = document.getElementById('pictureframe');
        var pictureframe_img = pictureframe.children[0];

        var imgarray = document.getElementById('pictures').querySelectorAll('img');
        for(let i=0; i<imgarray.length; i++){
            imgarray[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                pictureframe.classList.replace('isHidden','isVisible');
                pictureframe_img.src = imgarray[i].src;
            });
        }

        pictureframe_img.addEventListener('click', function(){
            pictureframe.classList.replace('isVisible','isHidden');
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

This works fairly well, in that when I click the image, the `pictureframe` is "front and center", and when I click the pictureframe, it does disappear nicely.

However, when I go back and forth between mobile, things start to look bad.

I have the `max-height` set, which works well on desktop, but on mobile, the edgs are clipped off. If I reverse it, set the `max-width` then it will also work fine on desktop, but the top and bottom will be clipped off on mobile.

I cannot seem to find the right balance so that it looks good on desktop and mobile. It seems that I may need to dynamically set either the `max-height` or `max-width` depending, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to go.

---

**EDIT:**

Here is a jsfiddle with a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/1uqgoc8w/

Comment: Cna you provide a link to a working code?

Comment: @LOTUSMS Added a JSFiddle

Comment: 'things start to look bad' is too vague, you need to state what it should look like in either mode. Also, in Firefox, the fiddle shows no effect at all. The image just sits there. I added `* { outline: 1px dashed }` to the CSS to see what the elements do. Image overflows as expected when resizing the fiddle 'run' frame.

Comment: @RenevanderLende I did say what that means; when I said "I have the max-height set, which works well on desktop, but on mobile, the **edges are clipped off**. If I reverse it, set the max-width then it will also work fine on desktop, but the **top and bottom will be clipped off on mobile**." In general, I don't want the image to be clipped on mobile.

Comment: problem is that you're using fixed, which makes it relative to the window and not the container so 90% would be of the document's height and not the container nor the view

Comment: also adding box-sizing would make sure it wont grow bigger than the set max height

Comment: here is a working example, if its what you wanna achive 
https://jsfiddle.net/d6r1ubt7/

Comment: @Breezer If I do not make it `fixed` then when I scroll down my page of images here and click a thumbnail, the `pictureframe` opens way up at the top of the page, and I have to scroll up to see it. I used `fixed` to keep it where I am within the page.

Comment: @Brian I see, but my solution just added box-sizing so everything else should work as intended

Comment: @Breezer I tried your solution; however, the way it is, the left and right of the image are still clipped on mobile.

Comment: @Brian add max-width:100%; or 100vw it should do the trick im certain

Comment: @Breezer Yes, that fixed it for mobile; but, now the image is clipped on the top and bottom for desktop browsers. I need a way so it is not clipped on desktop or mobile.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly You want to make sure it shows the entire frame in. WRD.

Try using the flex box

```
    #pictureframe {
        /* width: 100% */
        background-color: #00000066;
    }

    #pictureframe > img {
        /* max-height: 90%; */
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        border: solid 2em #000000;
        border-radius: 1em;
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        display: flex;
        width: 80%;
    }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1uqgoc8w/)

First you had an issue missing a closing semicolon on the width which broke the background (Unrelated but keep a linter handy for this stuff)

I kept your fixed positioning and added a display: flex to make use of the entire viewport real estate and set the width to 80% so that it creates a padding from the viewport edges. If you want it to extend to the edges, keep it at 100% width.

If you are looking to fill the entire screen, you are not going to be able to do this without clipping unless you are resizing your screen proportionally with the image size, you can however put the images in a json file and resource to them from css as `background-image: url ('PATH');` and make sure that you set the `background-size; cover`. But again, this also clips

Vieport proportion never equals to image proportions

Answer (score 0):

Working Example if understood correctly :
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/sLf64wpm/11/)

```
#pictureframe {
    width: 100%
    background-color: #00000066;
}

#pictureframe > img {
    max-height: 90%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    right:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: solid 2em #000000;
    border-radius: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

just add top,left & right position to 50%